# Open source data migration tool

Tags: database, open-source

My requirement is to migrate data from MySQL to PostgreSQL. Is there any free data migration tool which could do this effectively?

I have some huge data in MySQL which I need to convert to a PostgreSQL database. Henceforth I am looking for a **data migration tool** which could migrate tables (along with indexes, constraints, etc.) and data. I found [Swiss SQL Data Migration tool](http://www.swissql.com/products/datamigration/data-migration.html) to fit my requirement, but sadly it is not open source.

Is there some nice tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This list might help:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Scripts.2C_programs

For pure data migration you might want to look into [Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/), an open-source [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) (Extract-Transform-Load) tool.